# Recalling a string using a boolean value within a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a List `'SMSStore'` which contains a `[boolean, string1, string2]` eg.

```
[(False, 'roro', '07189202003'), (False, 'rtptp', '07189202003'), (True, 'rtptp', '07189202003')]
```

I want to have a function which will loop through the list, check the boolean and return all the string1's of the False booleans.

```
class SMSMessage(object):

    def __init__(self, hasBeenRead, messageText, fromNumber):
        self.hasBeenRead = hasBeenRead
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.fromNumber = fromNumber


hasBeenRead = False

**def get_unread_messages(hasBeenRead):
    for i in SMSStore[:][0]:
        if hasBeenRead == False:
             return messageText**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple *list comprehension* for a simple issue:

```
...

def get_unread_messages(l):
    return [t[1] for t in l if not t[0]]


l = [(False, 'roro', '07189202003'), (False, 'rtptp', '07189202003'), (True, 'rtptp', '07189202003')]
print(get_unread_messages(l))
```

The output:

```
['roro', 'rtptp']
```